# Simple function in Matlab executes more that 30 seconds

Tags: matlab

Why this simple function called test executes more than 30 seconds in Matlab?

This is simple code that creates tridiagonal matrix for given vectors **a,b** and **c**. But loop in function **test** last forever. Every time I run this file it needs 30 seconds to execute, is it normal?

```
m=100000;

a = [0,5*ones(1,m-1)];
b = 10*ones(1,m);
c = 2*ones(1,m-1);
d = 10*rand(m,1);

A=test(a,b,c);

function A = test(a,b,c)
n= length(b);
A = sparse(n,n);

for i=1:n-1
    A(i,i)=b(i);
    A(i+1,i)=a(i+1);
    A(i,i+1)=c(i);
end

A(n,n)=b(n);

end
```

Comment: You are reallocating the sparse matrix data structure at every loop iteration. Try this syntax for `sparse`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html#d123e1247028

Comment: Better yet, skip the loops and use [`spdiags`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html#mw_28033fbc-1469-45db-a771-bd610b284485).

Comment: Try using the "Run and Time" button instead of the "Run" button. This may take a little longer as Matlab is performing extra processes, but when it completes it will tell you which lines are taking the longest.